# Android - How to create pdf document or printDocument with data from database

Tags: android, sqlite, pdf, android-sqlite, android-print-framework

I need to generate pdf document with data from database. I have looked bunch of examples, but I couldn't get this data from database into a pdf.

I have two models Receipt and Logs (Receipt has_many Logs). I want get data from Receipt into pdf and then all logs which belongs_to Receipt into that pdf. After that I'll need to print that pdf document form android device.

Here are my Receipt model.

```
@Table(name = "Receipt")
public class Receipt extends Model {
    @Column(name="Place")
    String place;
    @Column(name="ShippingNumber")
    String shippingNumber;
    @Column(name="Warehouse")
    String warehouse;
    @Column(name="Carrier")
    String carrier;
    @Column(name="LicencePlate")
    String licencePlate;
    @Column(name = "Driver")
    String driver;
    @Column(name = "Customer")
    String customer;
    @Column(name= "DestWarehouse")
    String destWarehouse;
    @Column(name = "Employee")
    String employee;
    @Column(name = "PriceType")
    String priceType;
    @Column(name = "PriceCorrection")
    Integer priceCorrection;
    @Column(name = "CreatedAt")
    Date createdAt;
    public List<Logs> getLogs(){
        return getMany(Logs.class,"Receipt");
  }
```

And here is my Logs model.

```
@Table(name = "Logs")
public class Logs extends Model {
        @Column(name="PlateNumber")
        String plate_number;
        @Column(name="SortID")
        String sort_id;
        @Column(name="Grade")
        String grade;
        @Column(name = "Diametar")
        double diameter;
        @Column(name="Length")
        double length;
        @Column(name="CreatedAt")
        Date createdAt;
        @Column(name="Receipt")
        Receipt receipt;
  }
```

I'll also paste code so you could see how am I displaying Receipts and Logs. 

 This is how I display Logs.

```
 public LogsArrayAdapter(List<Logs> logsList) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DisplayLogs.this);
            this.logsList = logsList;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return logsList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return logsList.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return logsList.get(position).getId();
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_logs, parent, false);
            }
            Logs log = logsList.get(position);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textNumber)).setText(log.plate_number);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSort)).setText(log.sort_id);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGrade)).setText(log.grade);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDiameter)).setText(log.diameter + "cm");
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLength)).setText(log.length + "cm");
            Log.d("Value", log.createdAt.toString());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAmount)).setText(String.format("%.2f m3", log.getM3()));
            return convertView;
     }
```

And this is how I display my Receipts.

```
public ReceiptAdapter(List<Receipt> receiptList) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DisplayRecepit.this);
            this.receiptList = receiptList;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return receiptList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return receiptList.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return receiptList.get(position).getId();
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_recepit, parent, false);
            }
            Receipt receipt = receiptList.get(position);
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rPlace)).setText(receipt.place);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rShipNumb)).setText(receipt.shippingNumber);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rEmployee)).setText(receipt.employee);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rWarehouse)).setText(receipt.warehouse);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rCarrier)).setText(receipt.carrier);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rLicence)).setText(receipt.licencePlate);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rDriver)).setText(receipt.driver);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rCustomer)).setText(receipt.customer);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rDestWareh)).setText(receipt.destWarehouse);
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rCreatedAt)).setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").format(receipt.createdAt));
            return convertView;
 }
```

Any advice and help is more than welcome. I'm really stuck with this and I need help. 
**QUESTIONS: Is it better and easier to generate pdf document with data from database and then print it or use android printDocument() and directly work with database? 
 How to pass variables from database into pdfDocument or printDocument?**

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to create a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper and then create your database. Once you have all your data in there, you will first need to extract it using a Cursor and then hold the data. You can create a pdf document using this following class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html

The model you have shown here will first have to be translated into SQL statements that Android can understand. The current model is not something that can be directly understood by Android.